# Fill multiple DIVs with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a definition block on my website, where it randomly picks a word from an array then displays it along with its IPA and definition.

I have a basic understanding of JavaScript, however this is really above me.

I have written some really basic, psuedo code, to demonstrate what I'd like to do. Any help on how to actually do it would be greatly appreciated!

**JavaScript:**

```
var Selector = Random(3)
var Definitions = [
    {
        "word":"House",
        "phonetic":"haʊs",
        "definition":"The part of a theatre where the audience is seated, also known as an auditorium."
    },
    {
        "word":"Apron",
        "phonetic":"ˈeɪprən",
        "definition":"In a traditional theatre, the part of the stage which projects in front of the curtain. In many theatres this can be extended, sometimes by building out over the pit."
    }, 
    {
        "word":"Barn Door",
        "phonetic":"bɑːn dɔː",
        "definition":"An arrangement of four metal leaves placed in front of the lenses of fresnel spotlights (qv) to control the shape of the light beam."
    }
 ]
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="word">{Definition.Selector.word}</div>
<div id="phonetic">{Definition.Selector.phonetic}</div>
<div id="definition">{Definition.Selector.definition}</div>
```

While I understand this is nothing like workable code, I hope it can give enough of a representation of my idea.

Which long story short is:
*Pick random number. Select item from array. Fill three divs with three pieces of content from that array item.*

Thanks for your time(and hopefully answers)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One viable solution

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) { 
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); 
}  
var Definitions = [
    {
        "word":"House",
        "phonetic":"haʊs",
        "definition":"The part of a theatre where the audience is seated, also known as an auditorium."
    },
    {
        "word":"Apron",
        "phonetic":"ˈeɪprən",
        "definition":"In a traditional theatre, the part of the stage which projects in front of the curtain. In many theatres this can be extended, sometimes by building out over the pit."
    }, 
    {
        "word":"Barn Door",
        "phonetic":"bɑːn dɔː",
        "definition":"An arrangement of four metal leaves placed in front of the lenses of fresnel spotlights (qv) to control the shape of the light beam."
    }
 ];
var rand=getRandomInt(0, Definitions.length);

$('#word').text(Definitions[rand].word);
$('#phonetic').text(Definitions[rand].phonetic);
$('#definition').text(Definitions[rand].definition);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="word"></div>
<div id="phonetic"></div>
<div id="definition"></div>
```

Comment: For the random integer, I would use `function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}` and then call `getRandomInt(0, Definitions.length)`;

Answer (score 2):

And, to do the same thing depperm did using pure JavaScript, see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/et1fLLbx/1/).

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

var definitions = [
    {
        "word":"House",
        "phonetic":"haʊs",
        "definition":"The part of a theatre where the audience is seated, also known as an auditorium."
    },
    {
        "word":"Apron",
        "phonetic":"ˈeɪprən",
        "definition":"In a traditional theatre, the part of the stage which projects in front of the curtain. In many theatres this can be extended, sometimes by building out over the pit."
    }, 
    {
        "word":"Barn Door",
        "phonetic":"bɑːn dɔː",
        "definition":"An arrangement of four metal leaves placed in front of the lenses of fresnel spotlights (qv) to control the shape of the light beam."
    }
 ];

var index = getRandomInt(0, definitions.length);

document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = definitions[index].word;

document.getElementById('phonetic').innerHTML = definitions[index].phonetic;

document.getElementById('definition').innerHTML = definitions[index].definition;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! I chose the other answer simply because it was first. My site already runs jQuery so that wasn't an issue. I appreciate your JS only answer though.